# Tensorflow: Slicing a Tensor into overlapping blocks

Tags: tensorflow

I have a 1D tensor that I wish to partition into overlapping blocks. I'm thinking of something like:
 `tensor = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])`

```
overlapping_blocker(tensor,block_size=3,stride=2)
=> [[1 2 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7]]
```

So far I've only found ways to partition a tensor into non-overlapping blocks. Anybody knows of a way to solve this?

This needs to work for arbitrary input dimension (i.e. my input is like a `tf.placeholder([None])`

Comment: As of tf 0.11rc (some earlier), you can use many of the standard python slicing methods. For example if i0 = tf.constant(0) and i3 = tf.constant(i3) then your first block can be generated as just tensor[i0:i3]. Does this help?

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't really help. My input Tensor is arbitrarily long, so I can't just write a for loop which slices the vector N times. Also, I suspect it would be very inefficient to instantiate N independent tensor for N slices -- surely all the blocks need to fold into another dimension, rather than take up individual variable namespace...

Comment: I found the function tf.extract_image_patches extremely helpful here. You have to manually reshape your inputs and outputs, and you'll have to be careful about how you treat the first and last "patch". Besides those caveats, it did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [tf.nn.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d) to help. Basically, you take a sliding filter of block_size over the input, stepping by stride. To make all the matrix indexes line up, you have to do some reshaping.

### Generic solution

```py
import tensorflow as tf


def overlap(tensor, block_size=3, stride=2):
  reshaped = tf.reshape(tensor, [1,1,-1,1])

  # Construct diagonal identity matrix for conv2d filters.
  ones = tf.ones(block_size, dtype=tf.float32)
  ident = tf.diag(ones)
  filter_dim = [1, block_size, block_size, 1]
  filter_matrix = tf.reshape(ident, filter_dim)

  stride_window = [1, 1, stride, 1]

  # Save the output tensors of the convolutions
  filtered_conv = []
  for f in tf.unstack(filter_matrix, axis=1):
    reshaped_filter = tf.reshape(f, [1, block_size, 1, 1])
    c = tf.nn.conv2d(reshaped, reshaped_filter, stride_window, padding='VALID')
    filtered_conv.append(c)

  # Put the convolutions into a tensor and squeeze to get rid of extra dimensions.
  t = tf.stack(filtered_conv, axis=3)
  return tf.squeeze(t)


# Calculate the overlapping strided slice for the input tensor.
tensor = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=tf.float32)
overlap_tensor = overlap(tensor, block_size=3, stride=2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  in_t, overlap_t = sess.run([tensor, overlap_tensor])
  print 'input tensor:'
  print in_t
  print 'overlapping strided slice:'
  print overlap_t
```

Should give you the output:

```
input tensor:
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
overlapping strided slice:
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 3.  4.  5.]
 [ 5.  6.  7.]]
```

---

### Easier to understand solution

This is the initial version I got working, which doesn't allow for variable block_size, but I think it's easier to see what's going on with the convolution filters - we take a vector of 3 values, every stride steps.

```py
def overlap(tensor, stride=2):
  # Reshape the tensor to allow it to be passed in to conv2d.
  reshaped = tf.reshape(tensor, [1,1,-1,1])

  # Construct the block_size filters.
  filter_dim = [1, -1, 1, 1]
  x_filt = tf.reshape(tf.constant([1., 0., 0.]), filter_dim)
  y_filt = tf.reshape(tf.constant([0., 1., 0.]), filter_dim)
  z_filt = tf.reshape(tf.constant([0., 0., 1.]), filter_dim)

  # Stride along the tensor with the above filters.
  stride_window = [1, 1, stride, 1]
  x = tf.nn.conv2d(reshaped, x_filt, stride_window, padding='VALID')
  y = tf.nn.conv2d(reshaped, y_filt, stride_window, padding='VALID')
  z = tf.nn.conv2d(reshaped, z_filt, stride_window, padding='VALID')

  # Pack the three tensors along 4th dimension.
  result = tf.stack([x, y, z], axis=4)
  # Squeeze to get rid of the extra dimensions.
  result = tf.squeeze(result)
  return result
```

Comment: Is this an efficient way to do it? I'm not sure I trust tensorflow to optimize for this edge case where nearly all the values in the convolved filter are 0.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve the same using  `tf.extract_image_patches`.

EDIT-- API Change for TF 2.0

```
def overlapping_blocker(tensor,block_size=3,stride=2):
    return tf.squeeze(tf.image.extract_patches(tensor[None,...,None, None], sizes=[1, block_size, 1, 1], strides=[1, stride, 1, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID'))
```

For Older API:

```
tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

def overlapping_blocker(tensor,block_size=3,stride=2):
   return tf.squeeze(tf.extract_image_patches(tensor[None,...,None, None], ksizes=[1, block_size, 1, 1], strides=[1, stride, 1, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID'))

result = overlapping_blocker(tensor,block_size=3,stride=2)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(result.eval({tensor:np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], np.int32)}))

#[[1 2 3]
#[3 4 5]
#[5 6 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively straight forward approach using your example:

```
def overlapping_blocker(tensor,block_size,stride):
    blocks = []
    n = tensor.get_shape().as_list()[0]
    ilo = range(0, n, stride)
    ihi = range(block_size, n+1, stride)
    ilohi = zip(ilo, ihi).
    for ilo, ihi in ilohi:
        blocks.append(tensor[ilo:ihi])
    return(tf.pack(blocks, 0))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tensor = tf.constant([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.])
    block_tensor = overlapping_blocker(tensor, 3, 2)
    print(sess.run(block_tensor))
```

Output:

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 3.  4.  5.]
 [ 5.  6.  7.]]
```

Comment: tensor.get_shape()[0] is undefined. I'm looking for a solution that works for arbitrary input dimension, not only for specific input length.

Comment: You keep changing the constraints. If you want an answer fully specify the problem you're looking to solve.

Comment: I actually already specified "my input is arbitrarily long" in Oct 21st, as you can see in the comments to my question. But fair enough, I should have added that to my original question (which I have now through an edit)

Comment: If 'tensor' is fed through a placeholder then it must originally be a numpy array rather than a tf constant as I assumed in the example above. If so, the length of the corresponding np vector is easy to establish and pass to overlapping_blocker() as another python parameter, 'n', just as block_size and stride are passed. Wouldn't this meet your requirements? If so, I can modify the proposed solution accordingly.

Comment: use tf.stack instead of tf.pack in tensorflow version >= 1.0

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to get each rolling window as an individual tensor (i.e. each time you call `window.eval()` your window moves one over. You can use `tf.FIFOQueue` as well as `tf.train.range_input_producer` to make a queue that does this:

EDIT: updated to work with variable length tensors as requested in your original answer

```
def window_input_producer(tensor, window_size, capacity=32, num_epochs=None):
  num_windows = tf.shape(tensor)[0] - window_size
  range_queue = tf.train.range_input_producer(
      num_windows,
      shuffle=False,
      capacity=capacity,
      num_epochs=num_epochs
  )
  index = range_queue.dequeue()
  window = tensor[index:index + window_size]
  queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=capacity,
                       dtypes=[tensor.dtype.base_dtype],
                       shapes=[window_size])

  enq = queue.enqueue(window)
  tf.train.add_queue_runner(
      tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, [enq])
  )

  return queue.dequeue()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this question has been sufficiently answered, but you can use a python generator function to create overlapping windows:

```
def gen_batch():

# compute number of batches to emit
num_of_batches = round(((len(sequence) - batch_size) / stride))

# emit batches
for i in range(0, num_of_batches * stride, stride):
    result = np.array(sequence[i:i + batch_size])
    yield result

sequence = np.array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
batch_size = 3
stride = 2
gen = gen_batch()

print(next(gen))
[1,2,3]
print(next(gen))
[3,4,5]
...
print(next(gen))
[7,8,9]
```

Once you have defined your generator function, you can use TensorFlow's Dataset class to call each slice:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
gen_batch,
(tf.float64),
(tf.TensorShape([batch_size, dim_width])))

ds_out = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

print(sess.run(ds_out)))
[1,2,3]
print(sess.run(ds_out)))
[3,4,5]
...
print(sess.run(ds_out)))
[7,8,9]
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the function

```py
tf.signal.overlap_and_add(
    signal, frame_step, name=None
)
```

might be what you want. It solved my problem. It has been answered in