# Tensorflow overlapping mini batch

Tags: tensorflow, replace, sample, mini-batch

given some data in a dataset (or tensor)
`tensor = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])`

i need to create `N` batches of `M` tuples by drawing (say `4 x 3`) with replacement. an example minibatch could be

```
 [[1 2 3], [3, 4 5], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

The aim is to avoid creating a dataset in this form

```
[[1, 2, 3]
  [2, 3, 4]
  [4, 5, 6]
 ]
```

because of the massive redundancy. The batches should be created on the fly as I feed new mini-batches into the training process.

Comment: Do you use datasets API or session feed?

Answer (score 2):

I found one way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186583/tensorflow-slicing-a-tensor-into-overlapping-blocks), would you think this is optimal? or is it better to somehow deploy queues directly?

this code is based on the above link

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def gen_batch():

    # compute number of batches to emit
    num_of_batches = round(((len(sequence) - batch_size) / stride))

    # emit batches
    for i in range(0, num_of_batches * stride, stride):
        result = np.array(sequence[i:i + batch_size])
        yield result


sequence = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
batch_size = 3
stride = 1

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen_batch, tf.float64)
ds = ds.shuffle(100)
ds_out = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

sess = tf.Session()

print(sess.run(ds_out))
print(sess.run(ds_out))
print(sess.run(ds_out))
print(sess.run(ds_out))
print(sess.run(ds_out))
```

prints:

```
[3. 4. 5.]
[1. 2. 3.]
[2. 3. 4.]
[4. 5. 6.]
[5. 6. 7.]
```