# Tensorflow: extract sequential patches from a complex tensor of arbitrary length

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to figure out how to extract sequential patches from a complex valued tensor where the length is variable. The extraction is being performed as part of a `tf.data` pipeline.

If the tensor were not complex, I'd use `tf.image.extract_image_patches` as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186583/tensorflow-slicing-a-tensor-into-overlapping-blocks).

However, that function does not work with complex tensors. I have tried the following technique, but it fails because the length of the tensor is unknown.

```py
def extract_sequential_patches(image):
    image_length = tf.shape(image)[0]
    num_patches = image_length // (128 // 4)
    patches = []
    for i in range(num_patches):
        start = i * 128
        end = start + 128
        patches.append(image[start:end, ...])
    return tf.stack(patches)
```

However I get the error:

```
InaccessibleTensorError: The tensor 'Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(None, 512, 2), dtype=complex64)' cannot be accessed here: it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it. Defined in: FuncGraph(name=while_body_2100, id=140313967335120)
```

I have tried liberal decoration with `@tf.function`

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example (a complex tensor to give as input to the function)?

Comment: Can't you use [`tf.math.real`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/real) / [`tf.math.imag`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/imag) to split the real and imaginary parts of the numbers, apply the solution for real values to each of them and then join them back with [`tf.dtypes.complex`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/complex)?

Comment: @jdehesa I'd thought of that. I worried that all the splitting and recombining would add a lot of overhead, but maybe that is the way to go.

Comment: Looking again at your code, do you want a "sliding window" of patches, like in the linked answer, or just to "split" the data into parts of 128 elements, as in your code? Because I think what your code does is the same as a reshape?

Comment: I want a sliding window. I just put in 128 for simplicity. Will change it now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to adjust the calculation of the indices to make sure they don't go out of bounds, but leaving that detail aside, your code is almost what `tf.function` expects, except for the use of a Python list; you need to use TensorArray instead.

Something like this should work (the index calculations might not be entirely right):

```
@tf.function
def extract_sequential_patches(image, size, stride):
    image_length = tf.shape(image)[0]
    num_patches = (image_length - size) // stride + 1
    patches = tf.TensorArray(image.dtype, size=num_patches)
    for i in range(num_patches):
        start = i * stride
        end = start + size
        patches = patches.write(i, image[start:end, ...])
    return patches.stack()
```

You can find more details on why Python lists don't currently work in the [autograph reference docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#python-collections-in-tensorflow-control-flow).

That said, it might be faster to use the real/imag trick, if the kernel of extract_image_patches is optimized. I recommend testing both approaches.